# New To Format Date Object

Tags: javascript

I have a long value(1328005340400), I want to display the date format as "Tuesday, January 31, 2012 3:52:20 PM", How to format it in javascript, I just used new Date(1328005340400).toLocaleString(), but it displays "Tuesday, January 31, 2012 3:52:20 PM" in firefox and "Tue Jan 31 2012 15:52:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)". How to make it as common format? can't we achieve without using third-party codes

Answer (score 2):

Consider http://momentjs.com/ :

```
var now = moment();
console.log(now.format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss a'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to give a look at the **[moment.js](http://www.momentjs.com)** JavaScript library.

Among many useful features, it gives you **[full control of the rendering of a date](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/display/format)**.

Below some samples from the documentation

```
var date = new Date(2010, 1, 14, 15, 25, 50, 125);
moment(date).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Sunday, February 14th 2010, 3:25:50 pm"
moment(date).format("ddd, hA");                       // "Sun, 3PM"
```

Considering your question, you'd achieve this with the following

```
var date = moment(1328005340400);
var str = date.format('dddd, MMMM D, YYYY h:mm:ss A');
```

**Note:** Of course, you could achieve this without any third-party library, but you would have to re-code most of the rendering and maintain the code by yourself. Beside this, Moment.js is very lightweight and released under the permissive MIT license.

Comment: @vignesh was this answer helpful?